# Where can we find the Apache Spark component in Talend

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, etl, talend

I'm unable to find the spark component in the Talend Data Integration (v5.6.1). I also need a good reference source to learn spark in Talend.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details about which version of Talend DI you are using, where you got the information about Spark and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Talend DI - not support Spark, need look Open Studio for BigData, and best to start from 6.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Big Data platform. Not the Data integration. (You need to pay a liscence or use a tiral for 30 day)

There is another type of job other than standard jobs.

More information here : https://www.talend.com/products/big-data